# XPATH- Simple query

Tags: xpath

```
<Item>
  <ASIN>0545010225</ASIN>
  <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Deathly-Hallows-Book/dp/0545010225%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJ5YASVREOJN4AKXQ%26tag%3Dws%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0545010225</DetailPageURL>
  <ItemAttributes>
    <Author>J.K. Rowling</Author>
    <Creator Role="Illustrator">Mary GrandPré</Creator>
    <Manufacturer>Arthur A. Levine Books</Manufacturer>
    <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
    <Title>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Book 7)</Title>
  </ItemAttributes>
</Item>
```

I need to show the ASIN of all items authored by J.K. Rowling. This is an example of one of the books that would fall into this category. What would be the Xpath that would accomplish this?

Comment: What do you have so far? Let us know where you've stuck, so we can point you to the right direction. This is rather a learning / teaching medium than a free homework site.

Comment: I know how to get the author but am unsure how to then return the ASIN of their books.     //Author[text()="J.K. Rowling"]    is what i have so far

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XPath expression for the ASIN numbers of all Items authored by J.K. Rowling:

```
/Item[ItemAttributes/Author = 'J.K. Rowling']/ASIN
```